# GStreamer plugin src -> opusdec sink gives "error: decoder not initialized"

Tags: c, gstreamer, opus

I have the following two pipelines to transmit opus encoded audio from server to client:

The server:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v alsasrc ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! audio/x-raw, rate=16000, channels=1, format=S16LE ! opusenc ! rtpopuspay ! udpsink host=0.0.0.0 port=4000
```

The client:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=4000 ! application/x-rtp,payload=96,encoding-name=OPUS ! rtpopusdepay ! opusdec ! autoaudiosink
```

I try to create a custom `GstElement` based plugin to replace `rtpopusdepay` in the client side with a hand-crafted one (to be backward compatible with an existing server implementation that doesn't use `rtpopuspay` but uses a hand-crafted byte-format to wrap the opus encoded data).

To test the concept I would like to use the pipelines above, but replace the client side with:

```
GST_PLUGIN_PATH=. gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=4000 ! simpacketdepay ! opusdec ! autoaudiosink
```

Where `simpacketdepay` is the plugin I created. The plugin is quite simple, it has fixed caps (ANY for its sink and "audio/x-opus" for its src). In its chain function I simply remove the payload `rtpopuspay` adds to the encoded opus stream (first 96 bits) and push the data forward.

The full code:

```
#include "gstsimpacketdepay.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/gstcaps.h>

GST_DEBUG_CATEGORY_STATIC (gst_simpacketdepay_debug);
#define GST_CAT_DEFAULT gst_simpacketdepay_debug

/* Enum to identify properties */
enum
{
    PROP_0
};

static GstStaticPadTemplate sink_factory = GST_STATIC_PAD_TEMPLATE(
    "sink",
    GST_PAD_SINK,
    GST_PAD_ALWAYS,
    GST_STATIC_CAPS("ANY")
);

static GstStaticPadTemplate src_factory = GST_STATIC_PAD_TEMPLATE (
    "src",
    GST_PAD_SRC,
    GST_PAD_ALWAYS,
    GST_STATIC_CAPS("audio/x-opus, rate=16000, channels=1, channel-mapping-family=0, stream-count=1, coupled-count=0")
);

/* Define our element type. Standard GObject/GStreamer boilerplate stuff */
#define gst_simpacketdepay_parent_class parent_class
G_DEFINE_TYPE(GstSimpacketdepay, gst_simpacketdepay, GST_TYPE_ELEMENT);

static GstFlowReturn gst_simpacketdepay_chain (GstPad *pad, GstObject *parent, GstBuffer *buf);

static void gst_simpacketdepay_class_init (GstSimpacketdepayClass * klass)
{
    GObjectClass *gobject_class;
    GstElementClass *gstelement_class;

    gstelement_class = (GstElementClass *) klass;

    /* Set sink and src pad capabilities */
    gst_element_class_add_pad_template (gstelement_class, gst_static_pad_template_get(&src_factory));
    gst_element_class_add_pad_template (gstelement_class, gst_static_pad_template_get(&sink_factory));

    /* Set metadata describing the element */
    gst_element_class_set_details_simple (
        gstelement_class,
        "simpacketdepay plugin",
        "simpacketdepay plugin",
        "Sim Packet depay",
        "Test"
    );
}

static void gst_simpacketdepay_init (GstSimpacketdepay * simpacketdepay)
{
    simpacketdepay->sinkpad = gst_pad_new_from_static_template (&sink_factory, "sink");
    simpacketdepay->srcpad = gst_pad_new_from_static_template (&src_factory, "src");

    gst_pad_use_fixed_caps(simpacketdepay->sinkpad);
    gst_pad_use_fixed_caps(simpacketdepay->srcpad);

    gst_element_add_pad (GST_ELEMENT (simpacketdepay), simpacketdepay->sinkpad);
    gst_element_add_pad (GST_ELEMENT (simpacketdepay), simpacketdepay->srcpad);

    gst_pad_set_chain_function (simpacketdepay->sinkpad, gst_simpacketdepay_chain);
}

static GstFlowReturn gst_simpacketdepay_chain (GstPad *pad, GstObject *parent, GstBuffer *inBuf)
{
    GstSimpacketdepay *filter = GST_SIMPACKETDEPAY(parent);
    GstMapInfo info;
    gst_buffer_map(inBuf, &info, GST_MAP_READ);

    const size_t inSize = info.size;
    printf("Incoming size %lu\n", info.size);
    gst_buffer_unmap(inBuf, &info);

    GstBuffer* outBuf = gst_buffer_copy(inBuf);

    GstMemory* const inMemory = gst_buffer_get_memory(inBuf, 0);
    GstMemory* const outMemory = gst_memory_share(inMemory, 12, inSize - 12);
    gst_buffer_remove_all_memory(outBuf);
    gst_buffer_prepend_memory(outBuf, outMemory);

    gst_buffer_map(outBuf, &info, GST_MAP_READ);

    printf("Outgoing size: %lu\n", info.size);
    fflush(stdout);
    gst_buffer_unmap(outBuf, &info);

    gst_buffer_unref (inBuf);

    GstFlowReturn result = gst_pad_push (filter->srcpad, outBuf);

    return result;
}

static gboolean simpacketdepay_plugin_init (GstPlugin * plugin)
{
    GST_DEBUG_CATEGORY_INIT (gst_simpacketdepay_debug, "simpacketdepay", 0, "simpacketdepay");

    return gst_element_register (plugin, "simpacketdepay", GST_RANK_NONE, GST_TYPE_SIMPACKETDEPAY);
}

#ifndef VERSION
#define VERSION "1.0.0"
#endif
#ifndef PACKAGE
#define PACKAGE "FIXME_package"
#endif
#ifndef PACKAGE_NAME
#define PACKAGE_NAME "FIXME_package_name"
#endif
#ifndef GST_PACKAGE_ORIGIN
#define GST_PACKAGE_ORIGIN "http://FIXME.org/"
#endif

GST_PLUGIN_DEFINE (
    GST_VERSION_MAJOR,
    GST_VERSION_MINOR,
    simpacketdepay,
    "FIXME plugin description",
    simpacketdepay_plugin_init,
    VERSION,
    "LGPL",
    PACKAGE_NAME,
    GST_PACKAGE_ORIGIN
)
```

The negotiations and everything goes well, until I push the first buffer to the source pad from `gst_simpacketdepay_chain` with `GstFlowReturn result = gst_pad_push (filter->srcpad, outBuf);`

Then I get the following error (pasted the [detailed debug log here](https://pastebin.com/D5D4rEEg))

```
0:00:00.510871708 42302 0x55fbd0c44000 LOG             audiodecoder gstaudiodecoder.c:2034:gst_audio_decoder_chain:<opusdec0> received buffer of size 160 with ts 0:00:00.006492658, duration 99:99:99.999999999
0:00:00.510877845 42302 0x55fbd0c44000 WARN            audiodecoder gstaudiodecoder.c:2084:gst_audio_decoder_chain:<opusdec0> error: decoder not initialized
0:00:00.510882963 42302 0x55fbd0c44000 DEBUG            GST_MESSAGE gstelement.c:2110:gst_element_message_full_with_details:<opusdec0> start
0:00:00.510896592 42302 0x55fbd0c44000 INFO        GST_ERROR_SYSTEM gstelement.c:2140:gst_element_message_full_with_details:<opusdec0> posting message: GStreamer error: negotiation problem.
0:00:00.510910301 42302 0x55fbd0c44000 LOG              GST_MESSAGE gstmessage.c:303:gst_message_new_custom: source opusdec0: creating new message 0x7f519c002910 error
0:00:00.510919198 42302 0x55fbd0c44000 WARN               structure gststructure.c:1861:priv_gst_structure_append_to_gstring: No value transform to serialize field 'gerror' of type 'GError'
0:00:00.510929043 42302 0x55fbd0c44000 DEBUG                GST_BUS gstbus.c:315:gst_bus_post:<bus1> [msg 0x7f519c002910] posting on bus error message: 0x7f519c002910, time 99:99:99.999999999, seq-num 43, element 'opusdec0', GstMessageError, gerror=(GError)NULL, debug=(string)"gstaudiodecoder.c\(2084\):\ gst_audio_decoder_chain\ \(\):\ /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstOpusDec:opusdec0:\012decoder\ not\ initialized";
0:00:00.510937098 42302 0x55fbd0c44000 DEBUG                    bin gstbin.c:3718:gst_bin_handle_message_func:<pipeline0> [msg 0x7f519c002910] handling child opusdec0 message of type error
0:00:00.510942210 42302 0x55fbd0c44000 DEBUG                    bin gstbin.c:3727:gst_bin_handle_message_func:<pipeline0> got ERROR message, unlocking state change
0:00:00.510947151 42302 0x55fbd0c44000 DEBUG                    bin gstbin.c:4065:gst_bin_handle_message_func:<pipeline0> posting message upward
0:00:00.510955219 42302 0x55fbd0c44000 WARN               structure gststructure.c:1861:priv_gst_structure_append_to_gstring: No value transform to serialize field 'gerror' of type 'GError'
0:00:00.510962328 42302 0x55fbd0c44000 DEBUG                GST_BUS gstbus.c:315:gst_bus_post:<bus2> [msg 0x7f519c002910] posting on bus error message: 0x7f519c002910, time 99:99:99.999999999, seq-num 43, element 'opusdec0', GstMessageError, gerror=(GError)NULL, debug=(string)"gstaudiodecoder.c\(2084\):\ gst_audio_decoder_chain\ \(\):\ /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstOpusDec:opusdec0:\012decoder\ not\ initialized";
```

`<opusdec0> error: decoder not initialized`? Do I need to do something special to initialize the opus decoder? What step do I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. When the plugin element enters playing state we should push a `gst_event_new_caps` event to the source pad. Even with fixed caps... I haven't found anything in the documentation that can explain this requirement.

So I added the following state change handler and the pipeline started to work:

```
static GstStateChangeReturn gst_simpacketdepay_change_state (GstElement *element, GstStateChange transition)
{
    const GstStateChangeReturn result = GST_ELEMENT_CLASS(parent_class)->change_state (element, transition);
    if (result == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
        return result;
    }

    switch (transition) {
    case GST_STATE_CHANGE_PAUSED_TO_PLAYING: {
        GstSimpacketdepay *filter = GST_SIMPACKETDEPAY(element);
        gst_pad_push_event(filter->srcpad, gst_event_new_caps(gst_pad_template_get_caps(gst_static_pad_template_get(&src_factory))));
    } break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I'm sad to see how underdocumented this part of GStreamer is.